# How to update the value of a specific input field instead of the td first child?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, html-table

I have added this code to my function in javascript and am successfully updating the tables first TD with the new values of the rows after the user clicks a button to push the row up or down, the issue is I am using a input field in this td and the input is removed and the value is now just a simple text/numeric character.

How can I change this snippet to update the input field within the first td as opposed to replacing the td content with the new values outside a input field.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('td:first-child'),
  function (elem, idx) { elem.innerHTML = idx + 1; }
)
```

Ok so with Archers help I have updated the code below and now have the functionality I am wanting. Thanks for all who participated in schooling this newbie ;)

```
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('td:first-child input[name^=sort]'), function (elem, idx) {
        elem.value = idx + 1;
```

By changing

```
 'td:first-child'
```

to

```
 'td:first-child input[name^=sort]'
```

I was able to reference the specific input field as opposed to all input fields in the first td column and no longer am replacing the input fields with plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the selector to target the input instead of the cell that it's in...

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('td:first-child input'),
    function (elem, idx) {
        elem.value = idx + 1;
    });
```

Comment: hey Archer, thanks for the insight, I tried the code, but as I have more then one input in the first td I am getting the consecutive number of those so my second row becomes 6 (5 input fieldsd in the first row then the second row starts at 6) is there a way to add the input name (sort[]) or the ID (#sort) so it only checks those inputs maybe?

Comment: Sure, adding the name is the best idea in this case (IDs should be unique - they become meaningless if they're duplicated).  Can you update the question to show the complete html of the first cell?

Comment: figured it out and updating the question with the final code.

Comment: Great - glad you got it working.  When you've posted the html I'll update this answer so it's more complete anyway.

Comment: Okay - no need to update this as I see you've added the extra info to resolve your issue in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use your code and change its body like this:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('td:first-child'), function(elem, idx){
     (elem.querySelector("input")||{}).value=idx+1; //use this line instead of your forEach body
});
```

[Try it online!](https://jsfiddle.net/amvqk3p7/5/)

Comment: actually when I tried adding this the functionality of the page did not work, I didn't downvote but my form is functioning off buttons and the selector is also not working when I add your code. thanks for trying though. it is appreciated.

Comment: do you check my online fiddle?? anyway it is important that your problem is solved.